# audio recorder in a service android studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, service, recorder

### audio recorder in a service android studio

Hello everyone,
I allow myself to ask you a question on android studio.

Indeed for a project I need to use an audio reorder in a service. (i.e. without my application being in the foreground)

at the beginning everything works fine, but after a few moments I only get 0's.

for it to work again I have to go back to my application (put it back in the foreground) so that the acquisition ca[n work again.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1OIve.png)

do you have any suggestions, thank you in advance

here my code

public class Detection extends Service  {

```
int mStartMode;
IBinder mBinder;
boolean mAllowRebind;



@Override
public void onCreate() {



}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {


    Thread a = new Thread(runnable);
    a.setPriority(Thread.MAX_PRIORITY);
    a.start();



    return START_STICKY;
}

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {

    return mBinder;
}

@Override
public boolean onUnbind(Intent intent) {


    return mAllowRebind;
}

@Override
public void onRebind(Intent intent) {
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {


}

private Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        final int RECORDER_SAMPLERATE = 20000;
        final int RECORDER_CHANNELS = AudioFormat.CHANNEL_IN_MONO;
        final int RECORDER_AUDIO_ENCODING = AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT;
        int BufferElements2Rec = 1024;
        int BytesPerElement = 2;

        int bufferSize = AudioRecord.getMinBufferSize(RECORDER_SAMPLERATE,RECORDER_CHANNELS,RECORDER_AUDIO_ENCODING);
        short[] buffer = new short[bufferSize];
        int[]bufferint = new int[buffer.length];

        AudioRecord recorder;


        recorder = new AudioRecord(
                MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC,
                RECORDER_SAMPLERATE,
                RECORDER_CHANNELS,
                RECORDER_AUDIO_ENCODING,
                BufferElements2Rec * BytesPerElement);


            recorder.startRecording();
            boolean AlwaysOn = true;
            int cpt = 0;
            while (AlwaysOn) {
                int value = 0;
                int bufferResults = recorder.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);                                    //valeur du buffer (ici on va ecrire nos valeurs dan le premier parametre)

                for (int i = 0; i < bufferResults; i++) {                                                                //on parcours le buffer

                    bufferint[i] = buffer[i];
                    value = buffer[i];
                    System.out.println(value);
                }
                cpt++;

                System.out.println("le cpt : " + String.valueOf(cpt));
                SystemClock.sleep(100);
            }

    }
};
```

}

Answer (score 0):

try

```
startForegroundService(new Intent(this,Detection.class));
```